# Can a user somehow change the state of a React component from console in the browser?

Tags: security, console, client, state, react-state

For example, a user can define a function and run it, select an element from document, alter it and do other similar stuff from the console. I am wondering if it is also possible for user to alter the state of certain component from the console that I don't want him/her to do so. I personally couldn't do it, but want to know if it is possible. And if yes, is there any ways of preventing it ?